# Spring Integration Cluster with aggregator

Tags: cluster-computing, spring-integration

we are building a cluster using SI that has an aggregator in it's flow. Here we found we have two options for the aggregator:

1. Use a LockRegistry (Redis, Zookeeper, etc)
2. Use a Zookeeper leader listener

After reading the docs I couldn't find what's the best option. In which scenarios is better a LockRegistry than a leader listener?

I appreciate any help with this doubt

thanks in advance

Regards,

Guzmán

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application requirements; with the leader listener, typically, only one instance is active; the other instance will take over when the first one dies.

If you want active-active, use global locks.

A shared `MessageGroupStore` is required in both situations.

Comment: Excelent Gary! thank you very much. So if I need active-active is better global locks and active-passive, leader listener